# Google Drive Keeps Crashing

Tags: sync, google-drive

- Environment: Microsoft Windows Server 2012 Standard

We have around 5000 file changes (new, delete, edit) in a Google Apps for Business environment. The changes all happen elsewhere (via Drive's web interface, other business processes that place files into Drive etc.)

This machine has the Google Drive (GD) client installed on it and 99% of any drive changes are to sync from Drive in the cloud. The machine has been around for a while, but has only had GD installed on it for the last couple of weeks or so.

On pretty much a daily basis I find that the GD client has crashed and I have a nice friendly modal prompt telling me this. Click OK, GD disappears from the process list. Launch it again and hey presto it logs in, works out what to sync and starts syncing.

I need to find a better solution where even if GD dies it can auto recover. I realise I can run GD as a [service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148768/google-drive-as-service-or-background-operation), and then auto restart the service.

However before I go and do this I was wondering if:

1. Whether the service approach would be any more robust as I would be coercing an application that currently shows a modal dialog box into a non visual service, so all I would end up with is a service that appears to be running, but is actually blocked because of the modal dialog.
2. Anyone had a better solution?